# PHP API FACEBOOK - Users post to facebook page and personal wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a contest where a submitted form will:

1. write a comment on the wall of Facebook staff and
2. write a comment on the wall of my page

I had no problems with step 1, but step 2 does not work. My code is as follows:

connect.php

```
<?php
//include the Facebook PHP SDK
include_once 'facebook.php';

//instantiate the Facebook library with the APP ID and APP SECRET
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'CRYPT FOR THIS FORUM',
    'secret' => 'CRYPT FOR THIS FORUM',
    'cookie' => true
));

//Get the FB UID of the currently logged in user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//if the user has already allowed the application, you'll be able to get his/her FB UID
if($user) {
    //start the session if needed
    if( session_id() ) {

    } else {
        session_start();
    }

    //do stuff when already logged in

    //get the user's access token
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    //check permissions list
    $permissions_list = $facebook->api(
        '/me/permissions',
        'GET',
        array(
            'access_token' => $access_token
        )
    );

    //check if the permissions we need have been allowed by the user
    //if not then redirect them again to facebook's permissions page
    $permissions_needed = array('publish_stream', 'read_stream');
    foreach($permissions_needed as $perm) {
        if( !isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1 ) {
            $login_url_params = array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream',
                'fbconnect' =>  1,
                'display'   =>  "page",
                'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
            );
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
            header("Location: {$login_url}");
            exit();
        }
    }

    //if the user has allowed all the permissions we need,
    //get the information about the pages that he or she managers
    //id pag sposiamo è 494659577226200
    $accounts = $facebook->api(
        '/me/accounts',
        'GET',
        array(
            'access_token' => $access_token
        )
    );

    //save the information inside the session
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    $_SESSION['accounts'] = $accounts['data'];
    //save the first page as the default active page
    //$_SESSION['active'] = $accounts['data'][0];*/

    //redirect to manage.php
    header('Location: manage.php');
} else {
    //if not, let's redirect to the ALLOW page so we can get access
    //Create a login URL using the Facebook library's getLoginUrl() method
    $login_url_params = array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream',
        'fbconnect' =>  1,
        'display'   =>  "page",
        'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);

    //redirect to the login URL on facebook
    header("Location: {$login_url}");
    exit();
}

?>
```

newpost.php

```
<?php
//include the Facebook PHP SDK
include_once 'facebook.php';

//start the session if necessary
if( session_id() ) {

} else {
    session_start();
}

//instantiate the Facebook library with the APP ID and APP SECRET
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'CRYPT',
    'secret' => 'CRYPT',
    'cookie' => true
));

//get the info from the form
$parameters = array(
    'message' => $_POST['message'],
    'picture' => $_POST['picture'],
    'link' => $_POST['link'],
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'caption' => $_POST['caption'],
    'description' => $_POST['description']
);

//add the access token to it
$parameters['access_token'] = $_SESSION['active']['access_token'];

//build and call our Graph API request
$newpost = $facebook->api(
    '/494659577226200/feed',
    '/me/feed',
    'POST',
    $parameters
);

//redirect back to the manage page
header('Location: manage.php');
exit();
```

494659577226200 = FBPAGEID

PROBLEM IS '/494659577226200/feed', and error AuthCode 200...

Comment: `$newpost = $facebook->api(
    '/494659577226200/feed',
    '/me/feed',
    'POST',
    $parameters
);` should be $newpost = $facebook->api(
    '/494659577226200/feed',
    'POST',
    $parameters
);

Comment: nothing to do... i think that there's a problem for the auth with pages... token problem??? Work with facebook API is a nightmare... bad documentation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your user's to give your app `manage_pages` permission to post to their pages they manage on behalf of them. Check out their permissions doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/), See `Page Permissions` section.

Quoted from docs:
`manage_pages`

> Enables your application to retrieve access_tokens for Pages and Applications that the user administrates. The access tokens can be queried by calling //accounts via the Graph API. This permission is only compatible with the Graph API, not the deprecated REST API. 
>   See here for generating long-lived Page access tokens that do not expire after 60 days.

Once you get this permission, you can then make a wall post using [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)